# ReactJS Hooks UseRef returns null

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using a react-hook to copy the styling from the span element to the input element. This component switches from being a span to an input if the edit state becomes true. However I want to keep the styling of what's inside the span. So far, this doesn't work and inputEl always return null.

I'm open to new ideas to implement this.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
const Editable = props => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
  let children = props.children;
  const spanEl = useRef(null);
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setEdit(!edit);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    inputEl.current.served.style = spanEl.current.style;
  }, [inputEl]);
  if (edit) {
    return <input ref={inputEl} onClick={handleClick} value={children} />;
  } else {
    return (
      <span ref={spanEl} onClick={handleClick}>
        {children}
      </span>
    );
  }
};

export default Editable;
```

Comment: possible typo: `inputEl.served`

Comment: This code will throw run time error (inputEl.served.style), please provide a producible example.

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is Run time error is because initially your condition is false so it will go into the `else` block instead of `if` block and in your `else` block there is no `<input />` element. As you know that the `useEffect` run at the time of page loading, so you can't use `inputEl.current.served.style` in **useEffect** which don't even exist.

One thing you can do is :

**Either** Add this code- `<input hidden ref={inputEl} onClick={() => handleClick()} value="value" />`
in your `else` block

**OR** Add an initial value of `inputEl.current.served.style` in your ref in `const inputEl = useRef(null);` instead of null here.

you can refer [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-fire-q178h) for the demo.

Comment: using ```hidden``` flag inside of your ```<input />``` tag will not impact on your UI because this will never be shown. And one more thing, if you want to use ```<input ref={inputEl} onClick={handleClick} value={children} />;``` then it will throw warning in your console, So better remove the ```value``` inside of ```<input />``` tag or replace that ```onClick``` with ```onChange```.